# Streaming Kmeans Mahout

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

Can anyone explain to me,coceptually, how streaming kmeans algorithm works,and when would you recommend using it? I am not able to find much about it, and I would like to use Mahout implementation of it for clustering sensor data and possibly anomaly detection.

Thanks

Comment: I would actually not use mahout at all... it's surprisingly expensive and slow. Which is probably why they're rewriting it as of now to not use MapReduce anymore: https://mahout.apache.org/

Comment: Ok, thanks for your opinion, but can you tell me the concept of streaming kmeans? And by the way, I think that it will be much faster when they finish the moving to Spark...

Comment: Only those parts they rewrite... the legacy MR versions will remain really slow, I guess. Streaming k-means - probably they implemented the macqueen algorithm instead lloyds.